# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions, Version=3.1.0.0 in windows 10 machine

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, windows-10, dotnet-core-pack

I am trying to run my Dotnet-Core web Api project in windows 10 machine. But I am facing runtime error. I 'm not allowed to change the Application nuget version too

```
>fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
          Connection id "0HMLLR56JLU26", Request id "0HMLLR56JLU26:0000000B": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
    System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. Format of the executable (.exe) or library (.dll) is invalid.
    File name: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileContext.get_RequestHeaders
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileContext.ComputeIfMatch()
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileContext.ComprehendRequestHeaders()
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileContext.ServeStaticFile(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
```

[image]

Comment: Make sure your target SDK matches your dll version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer here lies in - `BadImageFormatException`. One of these

- Your app is compiled for one architecture (x64 or x86) but your Web Server pool runs different one
- One of the 3rd party DLLs is of incompatible architecture (**your case**)
- One of your DLLs is of incompatible architecture.
- DLL is compiled for the wrong platform. e.g. running DLL compiled for .net4.8 in the .netcore (**your case**)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So do I need to install any other dotnet Core pack?

Comment: You need to investigate internet server thread, your dlls and .netcore dlls packed into your published package. It seem that you don't have correct dlls. or your pool thread is not configured to run .net core. 
You should post more information about your internet server and thread pool, etc.

Comment: still this is not published one. currently I'm running with visual studio 2019 Professional. This app is working with other guys. The thing is  I started working in new laptop with windows 10. So still I am unable to run the application

Comment: @ChamathViduranga this is kind information you need to post in your question. when you say *"new laptop with windows 10"* you must post, what OS is this - 64bit/32bit. Same for VS and all. There are many variables. How do you debug? There are several ways usually. You need to post all these specs to make this picture clear. Also!!! your project's build settings. And so on.

Comment: One thing we know for sure. You have mismatch of your DLL architecture and the .net runtime.

Comment: Thanks a lot @T.S it works when I Repair my dotnet run time version :)